# install mysql root password reset windows 7

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, reset

I just finished installing MySql 5.7.9 on a Windows 7 machine but am unable to connect - I keep getting the error `Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306`. Here's what I tried:

1. Installed MySql using the Windows installer
2. During installation, the installer asked me for a root password which I set.
3. However on reading the logs, it stated:

   - Attempting to run MySQL Server with --Initialize-insecure
   - Running process: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
   - Waiting for the server stops: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
   - [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
   - [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
   - [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
   - [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
   - [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: ***.
   - [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
   - **[Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.**
   - Finished initialize database
   - Ended configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]
   - Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
   - Starting MySQL as a service

So even though I supplied the installer a password for root, it still ended up creating a root account with no password!

When I tried to change the password by following these instructions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

I get the error:

- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.702132Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.9-log) starting as process 5772 ...
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.702132Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.702132Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.702132Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.717732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.717732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.717732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.717732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.764532Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.764532Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of bufferpool
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.795732Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.795732Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
- 2015-10-28T15:04:08.795732Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGEENGINE failed.
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
- 2015-10-28T15:04:09.123333Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

This is where I can't really figure out how to move forward. I have also tried uninstalling MySql server, deleting the programData folder to get rid of all User info, and then reinstalling it, but the same thing happens. Please help!

Comment: It could be a file permissions issue. Make sure you are a computer administrator and in addition to that use "Run As Administrator" for the command prompt and Workbench, or disable UAC.

Comment: Tried both - disabling UAC as well as Run as Administrator :(

Comment: When you uninstall, does the ibdata1 file persist? Find that file (before uninstalling) and then uninstall MySQL. If that file is still there delete it (along with the entire folder structure it is in, if you are sure it is all MySQL related.

Comment: Turns out that when I was installing MySql, I added another administrator (other than root) as well - that user seems to be working fine. I'll just continue with that user until I need root for something very specific - have already spent hours trying to fix this! I miss OSX.